# How to access objectNames of objects in ApplicationWindow of QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

How to access `objectName` of children of `ApplicationWindow`?

With `ApplicationWindow`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: head
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle{ height:1; width: 1; objectName: "AA"}
    Rectangle{ height:1; width: 1; objectName: "BB"}

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        console.log("parent.data[0].objectName", head.data[0].objectName)
        console.log("parent.data[1].objectName", head.data[1].objectName)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
qml: parent.data[0].objectName ApplicationWindow
qml: parent.data[1].objectName
```

---

With `Window`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: head
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle{height:1; width: 1; objectName: "AA"}
    Rectangle{height:1; width: 1; objectName: "BB"}

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        console.log("parent.data[0].objectName", head.data[0].objectName)
        console.log("parent.data[1].objectName", head.data[1].objectName)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
qml: parent.data[0].objectName AA
qml: parent.data[1].objectName BB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `data`, we have to access `contentData` with respect to `ApplicationWindow`

```
Component.onCompleted:
    {
        console.log("parent.data[0].objectName", head.contentData[0].objectName)
        console.log("parent.data[1].objectName", head.contentData[1].objectName)
    }
```

From: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#contentData-prop

> contentData : list
>
> This default property holds the list of all objects declared as
> children of the window.
>
> The data property allows you to freely mix visual children, resources
> and other windows in an ApplicationWindow.
>
> If you assign an Item to the contentData list, it becomes a child of
> the window's contentItem, so that it appears inside the window. The
> item's parent will be the window's contentItem.
>
> It should not generally be necessary to refer to the contentData
> property, as it is the default property for ApplicationWindow and thus
> all child items are automatically assigned to this property.